# MySQL Select last 6 month ago or if result sum less 100 the 100 last inserted rows

Tags: mysql, date, if-statement

I'm looking for a MySql query who returns **last 6 months ago update data OR/AND, if the sum of results is less than 100, the next n rows to complete to 100**.

The table create query :

```
CREATE TABLE `content` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text,
  `lastUpdate` date NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `content`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `content`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=10175;
```

The first part of the query is :

```
 SELECT *
FROM content,
     categories
WHERE categories.id = content.id_cat
  AND lastUpdate > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
ORDER BY lastUpdate DESC,
         content.id DESC,
         content.title ASC
```

I don't find explanations to do this. Someone could help me ?

Comment: `the next n rows to complete to 100` ... what is the logic which determines what these "next n rows" are?

Comment: If you want to use the current ordering to also choose the stop-gap records (to make the total 100 in case the query returns less than that), then all you need to do is to remove the `DATE_SUB` check and add `LIMIT 100` to the end of your query.

Comment: This query should return the last updated articles. But if all the articles are updated older than 6 months, i want to selct the n (100?) last inserted id to have something to display.
And if there is only two updated articles in this time, i want to select the 98 last inserted articles.

Comment: What column(s) determine the last _inserted_ status?  Presumably `lastUpdate` is something else then?

Comment: The column who determine the last insert article may be the auto increment one : id

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sorry, i didn't know. I have edited my post.

Comment: Can you confirm that your desired result would be as follows: (All records where lastUpdate <= now - 6 months) OR (top 100 records order by lastUpdate descending)?

Comment: The results would be as follow :
if(All records where lastUpdate <= now - 6 months) < 100 records
then add to this previous records the 100 - (previous records) top records

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you want all of the records within the last 6 months; if that set has fewer than 100 records, then select the top 100 most recent records.

One approach is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM content
INNER JOIN categories
ON categories.id = content.id_cat
WHERE lastUpdate > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
OR content.id IN (SELECT content.id FROM content
INNER JOIN categories
ON categories.id = content.id_cat
ORDER BY lastUpdate DESC,
         content.id DESC,
         content.title ASC
LIMIT 100)

ORDER BY lastUpdate DESC,
         content.id DESC,
         content.title ASC
```

Comment: I thank you but it seems that "TOP" is not available with Mysql. Only with SQL Server (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp).

Comment: Edited to change query to use LIMIT 100 rather than Top.